# Android Studio Local path doesn't exist (classes folder instead of apk)

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello I am having this error

```
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\myuser\AndroidStudioProjects\Myapp\build\classes\debug\Myapp.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/mypackage
Local path doesn't exist.
```

when uploading to my device. 
I see that Myapp.apk gets created in apk folder as it should be.
But Android Studio tries to upload from classes\debug\

Do you know how to sort it out?
Thanks

Comment: Which version of Studio is this?

Comment: Somehow I fixed with gradlew clean and restart. It was 0.1.5. Thanks.

Comment: can you elaborate how you did it

Answer (score 16):

I just blogged about having the exact same problem. Hopefully this helps and works for you.

http://www.ninjacrab.com/2013/08/28/android-studio-local-path-doesnt-exist/

Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively you can go to Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files to restore the path.

Comment: I don't have this option in Tools -> Android (in IntelliJ 13)?

Comment: What worked for me was, run the project in debuggmode. After that I could generate apk. Strange...

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my similar problem by opening up the project .iml file and edited the incorrect APK_PATH declaration

Answer (score 0):

If you are using studio on Windows and your windows username contains special symbols like '&' - RENAME YOUR USERNAME (and user folder)!