# Running an application on android studio

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-studio, apk

I have created an android application project. I want to run it in a genymotion virtual device, but when i select the virtual device it gives me an error:

> Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: (nothing written in)

then, when i click ok, it says:

> Unexpected Error.
>   Local path doesn't exist. Local path doesn't exist. The project may need to be synced with Gradle files.

How can i solve the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256177/android-studio-local-path-doesnt-exist

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236515/android-studio-local-path-doesnt-exist-classes-folder-instead-of-apk

Comment: Above two links are useful .Please set path

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82388. Comment #33 in there has something which may help you.